# forcing https in htaccess with mvc showing 404 errors for js and css files

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to force https with my .htaccess file but when I do, the layout breaks and I get 404 errors in console for pretty much everything from css files to js files etc. I am using a MVC structure.

In my config file I have:

```
define('URLROOT', 'https://www.example.com');
```

In my header all my css files are called like this:

```
<link href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

My .htaccess looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
 RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Also, If I type in https://example.com it goes to https but if I just type in example.com it defaults to http which is also a problem.

Comment: Why the Rewrites to `public/`? I don't think they are necessary for the HTTPS force. And they look like the most likely cause for a 404 if `docroot/public/css/style.css` does not exist. Plus, you never get to your HTTPS rule as `.*` always matches and has the `L` (last) flag.

Comment: /public is where I have another .htaccess `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options -Multiviews
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /public
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
 </IfModule>`

Comment: Are your certificates OK?  Can you verify in the page source in your browser that the link href is to a valid page?  As for mod_rewrite, I use #enforce SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

to force SSL.

Comment: Am I meant to replace `https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}` with my own url or use it just like that?

Comment: Just leave it like that. %{VAR} denotes a variable. HTTP_HOST is your domain and REQUEST_URI is the path the user is requesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `http -> https` rule on top:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

Make sure to test in a new browser to avoid old browser cache.

Comment: this is working with www.domain.com but not with www.domain.com/something. Then you get an 404 error.

Comment: That is not related to these rules. Please open a new question with details and we shall help

Answer (score 1):

Place this on top of your .htaccess, make sure to change the domain name and you are set - all HTTP requests (even those to static files) will get redirected to HTTPS:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```